# Find GitHub issues I was once assigned to but not at the moment

Tags: github, github-issues

5-6 issues were assigned to me before I went for holiday. But at the moment only one issue is assigned to me. I want to find those issues that were assigned to me. If anyone can hint me a way for it please.